# OpenCV and the User Interface

Tags: image, user-interface, image-processing, opencv

I need to do a project on image processing using OpenCV and I am just starting to learn the basics, however I need to know one thing about the User Interface, can I design the UI using the libraries provided by OpenCV ? This includes forms, buttons and event handling or do I need to use some other language for the UI ?

Answer (score 9):

OpenCV provides a highgui library which contains minimum UI functionalities like ShowWindow, Trackbar,Mouse events etc. It is not useful for advanced GUI development.

Check out OpenCV documentation: [Link 1,](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_user_interface.html) [Link 2](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html)

And it is expanded by few more functions from qt for support like button etc. [Link 3](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#)

But for advanced GUI development, OpenCV is integrated with Qt. Qt is very advanced, highly stable framework and it is free and opensource. It is implemented in C++, so easy to use with OpenCV. More interesting thing is that, if you use Python for OpenCV, then Qt also has got python wrapper called [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) which covers almost all functions of Qt.

You can download Qt from [here.](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads) Checkout its [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) and [wide variety of tutorials.](http://qt.nokia.com/learning) Tutorials are very extensive for Qt. So it is not a difficult thing to learn.

Installation guide for OpenCV and Qt are found here: [Link](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/wiki/Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MFC using Microsoft Visual Studio for opencv ui 
Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library)! to Know more about MFC.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCVSharp](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/) is a great C# wrapper for OpenCV project. Its latest version 2.4.5 uses OpenCV 2.4.0 dlls. Check it out, too.